# Cloudfare is Blocking API calls to https://api.blockchain.info/ticker, it returns 403, and recaptcha challenge

Tags: api, ssl, cloudflare

Cloudfare is Blocking API calls to https://api.blockchain.info/ticker, it returns 403, and recaptcha challenge. This API call was working perfectly before i started using Cloudfare to secure my website. This problem started when cloudfare is implemented

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be using the incorrect / outdated URL -

https://www.blockchain.com/api/exchange_rates_api

According to the documentation it should be -

`https://blockchain.info/ticker`

If that still doesn't work, there are also other, authenticated, APIs available as well -

https://www.blockchain.com/api